# jMeter: upload sequentially named files

Tags: jmeter

I've several files containg POST body requests.I'd like to send those requests in parallel using jmeter.

Currently, I'm using `curl` + `parallel` command apporach.

Related curl command is like:

```
curl -s -X POST $FHIR_SERVER/ -H "Content-Type: application/fhir+json" --data "@patient-bundle-01.json"
```

Request bodies are files like `patient-bundle-xx`, where `xx` is a number. Currently, I'd like to send up to 1500 requests using this incremental pattern.

My approach using `parallel`:

```
doit() {
  bundle="$1"
  curl -s -X POST $FHIR_SERVER/ -H "Content-Type: application/fhir+json" --data "@patient-bundle-$bundle.json"
}
export -f doit
export FHIR_SERVER
seq -w 99 | parallel -j77 doit
```

How could I get this behavior using jmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element and specify desired start and end value

[image]

In your HTTP Request sampler add `${bundle}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference to the file name

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Another (easier) option could be using [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) plugin